# AD Users outside the building

Tags: active-directory

I've never had a customer ask me this, but they keep insisting if they have Active Directory and a Domain, that mobile[road warriors] users will not be able to login to their laptops if they are at home or away from the office. I told them that is would use "cache" creds to do this. Am I right or wrong? I've been told this and found a couple of forums saying the same thing. What is really going on and how are the laptops able to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, cached credentials are used to log in, unless you use a GPO to explicitly force your domain clients to *not* cache credentials.

Answer (score 2):

If the users have successfully logged into the domain from their laptops at least once then they'll be able to log in using cached credentials when they're disconnected from the domain, unless as Ryan points out you have a GPO preventing the use of cached credentials.